# .htaccess redirect domain to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have several domain names that point to the same IP address. I currently redirect them from the /default.asp file to the appropriate folder based on the SERVER_NAME. For example:

```
http://domain1.com redirects to http://domain1.com/folder1
http://domain2.com redirects to http://domain1.com/folder2
```

This works, but the urls display the folder name in the browser:

```
http://domain1.com/folder1/somepage.htm
```

And the user can't go to a page without entering the folder name:

```
http://domain1.com/somepage.htm // This fails because it isn't in the root folder.
```

Can I use the .htaccess file to (1) route page requests to the appropriate folder and (2) prevent the folder name from appearing in the browser?

That'd also move the redirection from the /default.asp file to the .htaccess file where it probably belongs.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like your VirtualHost directives in the `httpd.conf` file are messed up. Do you have access to those?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that the Document Root for `domain1` is in the wrong location. You can try to rewrite it with `.htaccess`, but it's not going to work.

Comment: Huh? "Document Root" is in the wrong location? I don't think anything is messed up, my domain works fine (I don't even have a .htaccess file at the moment). I'm asking if and how I can redirect a domain name so (1) the requests go to a specific folder and (2) if I can prevent the folder name from appearing in the browsers URL. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

RewriteCond %{lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}} ^www\.([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /home/%1/www$1
```

Comment: This answer assumes directory paths, systems, and naming conventions that the OP has not included in their original question. Furthermore, something like this \*should\* not work if the server has the proper permissions set up (in regard to your last rule).

Comment: It was an idea example. Giving "copy paste" answer doesn't teach anything. Have no idea what are you talking about the permissions. It's demonstration how it works. Of course you have to have permissions to access folder you are redirecting to. Giving -1 for that is simply being an ***.

Comment: On this site we strive to give real answers that can be shown in the code. Some of the posters may not be using the flavor of Linux you're used to (this looks like something from Redhat or CentOS). Some people may be using something like FreeBSD or Windows. The path you're referencing looks like a DocumentRoot which would be found in a VirtualHost declaration in the Apache Config.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` in an `.htaccess` file only has access to what is in the document root for the host where it resides. It can't see below the document root and it can't serve a page outside of the Document root. If their permissions were set so something at the ROOT level of the OS (in this case the `/home` folder) was web accessible, then there would likely be an issue with permissions on the server.

Comment: If you did not check it, please don't say that it's os specific. This rule works as well on Debian as on Windows, of course changing directory names has to be done. The way the poster asks shows that it is general question, I really doubt that he really uses `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` - those have different registrars, registrants and second one is locked. Neither `folder1` and `folder2` as directory names.

Comment: The OP's question is about rewriting multiple domains. Not about changing case. Additionally your RewriteRule has a syntax error for `.htaccess`. If someone visited `www.subdomain1.example.com/folder1` your RewriteRule would present them with `www.subdomain1.example.com/home/subdomain1/wwwfolder1` which is definitely not the answer the OP is after. Also you're not explaining ANYTHING that you're doing in your actual "answer," so you're not being helpful at all, which is why you were given a `-1`.

Comment: That is not true. Rewrite rule acts on actual directories. Rewriting  to /home means that it will look for files in /home, not that it will change url to /home (!). Are You sure You have any idea about url rewriting? `www.subdomain1.example.com/home/subdomain1/wwwfolder1`??? Maybe just check that rule? It is rewriting domains, it has to lowercase the string so it would not matter if user types domain1.com or DOMAIN1.COM or dOmAiN.cOm ...

Comment: the browsers control whether they search case sensitively or not. There should not be any reason to worry about the case sensitivity of the domain itself. In regard to mod_rewrite RTM.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Not true again. Try on windows. You will see that it does not lowercase HTTP_HOST.